# imageMediaMetadata date missing when jpg upload via web drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Using the web client of Google Drive, I added a file image called "image.jpg."  This was done by dragging the image from the file system (Mac OS.x 10.9.5) to Chrome where I have my drive folder ready to receive the file.

"image.jpg" has EXIF data such "Date Time Digitized" and "Date Time Original, as confirmed by using Preview on the Mac, and the Inspector tool.  For sake of discussion, this date is:  "Dec 6, 2014, 3:52:45 PM".

Upon making a call to the API such as:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}
```

where fileId is the id of the file "image.jpg" in Drive, the resulting imageMediaMetadata does not contain date properties.  Below is the imageMediaMetadata.

"imageMediaMetadata": {
       "exposureTime": 0.053308000000000001,
 
       "flashUsed": true, 
       "cameraMake": "Nokia", 
       "isoSpeed": 100, 
       "exposureMode": "Auto", 
       "colorSpace": "sRGB", 
       "height": 918, 
       "width": 1632, 
       "meteringMode": "Average", 
       "location": {
            "latitude": 47.676632499999997, 
            "altitude": 0.0, 
            "longitude": -122.12224833333333
       }, 
       "aperture": 2.0, 
       "exposureBias": 0.0, 
       "rotation": 0, 
       "whiteBalance": "Auto", 
       "cameraModel": "Lumia 920"
  }

"date" (imageMediaMetadata.date) is not there.

Why is "date" not in the imageMediaMetadata? How to resolve?

Comment: There has not been a response yet.  However, a solution has been created.  Please connect with me if details are desired (include reply email as have received messages, but not able to reply).  Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue. After uploading file, meta data is missing. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Hi.  It has been awhile since first posting this question, sorry to see it still remains an issue.  Our solution was to read the actual image stream (introducing delay).  The EXIF data is in a specific location within the first (x) bytes of data (see the EXIF spec).  We started with an open source library that consumed the stream until recognize the EXIF data, and then extracted the actual date information from the image itself.  This process worked fairly well for most images, however a concern was different manufacturers.  Makes sense for Google to implement, please.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If possible, check your image file to see if it includes the Exif field:  Exif/Image/DateTime.   If it does not and you are able to add it, that would be a worthwhile test to see if it then produces a date in the metadata.